# Regex to parse html-elements and change them

Tags: regex, eclipse

Right now I need to change the name of an attribute of one of my coponents in all my html pages. To do that I want to regex search and replace it in eclipse.( [eclipse regex syntax](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/gla_42/ref/rregexp.html))

the component looks like this:

```
<exa:mycomponent attribute1="attr1" attribute2 ="attr2" ... >
```

or

```
<exa:mycomponent attribute1="attr1"
             attribute2 ="attr2" ... >
```

I tried it with

```
 <exa:mycomponent ([\S\s]*)attribute1([\S\s]*)>
```

but it also returns components different to "mycomponent" because there is a "mycomponent" there and another component uses the attribute, like this:

```
<exa:mycomponent attribute2 ="attr2" ... >

<exa:myothercomponent attribute1 ="attr2" ... >
```

which would replace the "attribute1" of the "myothercomponent"

is there a way to "break" at the first ">" to prevent it from finding a wrong component?
I tried it with

```
 <exa:mycomponent ([\S\s^>]*)attribute1([\S\s^>]*)>
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
<exa:(mycomponent)([\S\s]attribute1[\S\s]+?)>
```

example: **http://regex101.com/r/rA8rE0**

Comment: it doesnt work. I may have to add that the "attribute 1" hasn't to be the first attribute, so  <exa:mycomponent attribute2="attr1"
             attribute1 ="attr1" ... > is valid, too.

Comment: also, i want to replace "attribute1" by "anotherattribute".
This is kinda hard without seperating it from the stuff around it.

Comment: It's not really hard at all once you put the things into groups by using `(` ... `)`. Here's another example: http://regex101.com/r/uE1fW0. Notice the subtle change I made to the regex pattern and the items you said were hard to separate are separated. It's unclear whether you would want other things grouped or separate, but play with that and you'll find it's not that difficult.